# Replacement for a P-Channel Depletion MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

I've read some of the questions about P-Channel Depletion MOSFETS and I understand their availability is very limited and often expensive. So what I'm hoping to discover with those that view and respond to my question, is an appropriate replacement for a P-Channel Depletion MOSFET for my circuit design.

A bit of background:
P-Channel DMOSFET was perfect for me because I need to have two wires shorted together a majority of the time. A P-channel DMOSFET will connect these two nodes with minimal voltage between drain and source when the gate is grounded; which is exactly what I want because the two wires I'm connecting is actually shorting a wire to GROUND in the absence of an external signal.
Once this external signal is connected, I also route it appropriately to the gate of the DMOSFET so it opens the switch, no longer grounding the drain.

EDIT1:
This is a basic depiction of the part of the circuit in question (omitting basic resistors and capacitors):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYq8NS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M2 is a low forward voltage diode so VCC from the battery doesn't open the M1 switch. 
M1 connects the 'Signal' to ground, until a charger is connected in which case the Signal is disconnected from the part of the circuit I have illustrated.
The device on V_out is drawing less than 1mA which is highly beneficial for the battery life.
/EDIT1

An obvious alternative to this design is using an N-Channel Enhancement MOSFET and an inverter to the Gate, but I'm trying to make this design as minimal (physically) as possible so I can enclose it in a 3D printed design as small as possible for portable purposes.
The design without an inverter is also preferable because there would be less current draw from the battery a majority of the time, without the constant current drain and power consumption that would be occuring in the inverter.

The switching speed need not be fast, and there is not significant current connected to the MOSFET (milli-amps in my design)

Is there any other ideas?

Thanks :)

Edit1: Included basic schematic and brief explanation.

Comment: Can you use the built-in schematic editor to draw a schematic? (Simply use the existing PMOS symbol there and make a text note on the schematic that it's supposed to be depletion -- CircuitLab hasn't a clue about depletion FETs)

Comment: Also, could a JFET work for your job?

Comment: Exactly how many milli-amps need to be switched to Ground, and what voltage drop is acceptable? What voltage does the signal provide when connected, and what is the battery voltage?

Comment: a relay using the NC contact

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I'm having a read of JFETs (I haven't used them before). They have a similar application in that they are normally closed, and I may be able to replace M1 with a JFET but due to their larger Rdson it would be inefficient and inappropriate to replace M2 with a JFET :(

Comment: @jsotola, I've added a basic schematic showing how the two MOSFETS were intended to be used. Can I still replace the MOSFETS with a relay as you have mentioned?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, battery and charging voltage is 5V. The current flowing from drain to source on M1 is minimal to none - less than milliamp.
The current through M2 will be much higher as it charges the battery (e.g. half an Amp depending on charging adapter)
Both switches it is desirable if the forward voltage drop is as small as possible, millivolts for M1 and preferably of the order of 100mV for M2.